# Getting device info in iOS?

Tags: iphone, locale, ios

I'd like to find out and store information about a users device.

I'm looking for the date, the type (iPhone/iPod/iPad), the locale (Language) and location.

The date should be simple to get, as is the device type.

What code is used to find out the current locale/language of the device interface?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html - Thought that might be helpful, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [the `NSLocale` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can grab an instance of the current locale using `+currentLocale` or `+autoupdatingCurrentLocale`; the class defines a number of constants that you can use to get language and country information from that instance using its `-objectForKey:` method, e.g. `NSLocaleCountryCode` and `NSLocaleLanguageCode`.